# Is it possible to have 15 variables in a struct in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, storage

I have a struct with two variables bool, nine bytes 32 and three uint. The problems I want to add another bytes32 but I get this error "InternalCompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables."

```
struct xxxx{

    bytes32 id;
    bool x;
    //bool w;
    uint date;

    bytes32 a;
    bytes32 b;
    bytes32 c;
    bytes32 d;
    bytes32 e;


    bytes32 f;//Nuevo
    bytes32 g;//NUEVO
    bytes32 h;//NUEVO

    uint j;
    uint k;

    bool active;
    //bool active;
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code? Or a reduced version of your code that still gives this error?

Comment: Usually, the "Stack too deep" error happens when you have too many local variables.

Comment: I know what the error is, I also know that if you organize the bytes of the variables you can add other variables, I have tried but still I get an error: C.

Comment: @NicolasFloresMuñoz The error is not in the structure definition but the way you are using it. I've created structures with more than 30 members without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't in the `struct`. It's probably in the default getter function you get when cast a variable as the type defined in the struct and set visibility to `public`. In this case, the compiler tries to make a function that will return the scaler variables in the `struct`, and here you run into stack limitation.

Here is a (useless) contract with the `struct` extended to include more variables. There is no problem.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Stack {
    
    struct xxxx {

    bytes32 id;
    bool x;
    bool w;
    uint date;

    bytes32 a;
    bytes32 b;
    bytes32 c;
    bytes32 d;
    bytes32 e;


    bytes32 f;//Nuevo
    bytes32 g;//NUEVO
    bytes32 h;//NUEVO

    uint j;
    uint k;

    bool active;
    bool b1;
    bool b2;
    
    bytes32 added;
  }
  
  // xxxx public s;
}
```

If you uncomment the last line, then we have a problem.

You could, therefore, refrain from using `public` and just create your own getters to return portions of instances.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention that storing tonnes of metadata in contracts is usually not recommended.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think that if you try to instantiate a local variable of this type (i.e., `struct xxxx` inside a function), then you're likely to get the same "Stack Too Deep" problem. So it's not only about a getter function, and can appear in a bunch of other scenarios.

Comment: The OP didn't say what the scenario is so I took a guess about what might be causing it.

Comment: Also, passing such struct as input argument to another function will yield the same effect (though this is not supported in Solidity 0.4.24, but I guess possibly supported in later versions).

Comment: You saved my weekend! :-D :-D :-D